My Flutter app does not build for Android due to Kotlin Gradle issue
I tried running my flutter app on Android today and It popped an issue related to gradle while I tried to build.

Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher.
The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
project ':sign_in_with_apple' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1


What can I do?
